# How do I insert an alt="something-here" attribute into PHP code?

Tags: php

I have a semi-transparent icon located in the bottom-right of my screen.  It's obvious; it's an arrow pointing up, implying that the user can scroll to the top if the page or post is too long.

But I'd like it to have an **alt="Scroll to top"** attribute when the user hovers over the icon for a few reasons.  How can I achieve this?  The PHP code where the link is looks like this:

```
  public function plugin_action_links( $action_links )
  {
     array_unshift( $action_links, "<a href=\"" . STT_OPTIONS_URL . "\">" . __( 
   'Settings', 'scrollto-top' ) . "</a>" );

     return $action_links;
  }
```

If more information is needed, please let me know.  I've tried things, but they always break the code.  I'm sure I have to put something in the < a href part of this code, but I'm unsure as to the syntax I'd use, or where I'd use it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `alt` is only for images to be displayed when the image is not available. What you need is the `title` attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard; duly noted ... I'll include both alt and title attributes ... thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: No, please don't add alt to `<a>` it will be same like having `<a jkgjg="hhh">` i.e. invalid attribute. It will render your HTML invalid in case you ever run it through validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply add it in the anchor tag.

```
array_unshift( $action_links, "<a href=\"" . STT_OPTIONS_URL . "\" alt=\"Alt text Here\">" . __( 
   'Settings', 'scrollto-top' ) . "</a>" );
```

However if you want this to work cross browser you will need to provide the `alt` and `title` attribute.

The alt text is alternative text for the image when the image either cant be loaded or the user is using a screen reader. The title text is intended as the tooltip. However not all browsers see it this way so including both should work in all browsers

Comment: Thanks Cowls!  I ended up doing this: array_unshift( $action_links, "<a href=\"" . STT_OPTIONS_URL . "\" alt=\"Scroll to top\" title=\"Scroll to top\">" . __( 
   'Settings', 'scrollto-top' ) . "</a>" ); .... and while it still isn't displaying the tooltip text in any browser, I'm sure I can take things from here now that you pointed me in the proper direction.  It's kinda weird, 'cause the image doesn't even appear in my html output, so I can't see if the alt and title tags are there.  But I'll get it working soon!  Thanks a bunch for taking the time to help!

Comment: No, alt attribute is not part of anchor tag it will just be ignored by browsers and make the HTML invalid.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Jason,
am interesting this like problems in php, please update your code like this

```
 return array_unshift( $action_links, "<a href=\"" . STT_OPTIONS_URL . "\" alt=\"Alt text Here\" title=\"Scroll to top\">" . __('Settings', 'scrollto-top' ) . "</a>" );
```

Comment: Thank you Shamsudheen.  I did experiment with your code; it doesn't break anything, but it doesn't display the alt="" or title="" attributes.  Thank you for your time in trying to help me out with this issue!